# cannot read property 'count' of undefined discord.js

Tags: javascript, caching, discord, discord.js, typeerror

I am on  version 12 of discord.js, and I am making a giveaway command.

```js
let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle('Giveaway!')
            .setAuthor('Hosted by ' + message.author.username, message.author.avatarURL())
            .setDescription('The prize is **' + prize + '**!')
            .setTimestamp(Date.now() + ms(args[1]))
            .setColor("BLUE")
            let m = await channel.send(embed)
            m.react("")
            setTimeout(() => {
                if (m.reactions.cache.get("").count <= 1) {
                  message.channel.send(`Reactions: ${m.reactions.cache.get("").count}`);
                  return err('Not enough people reacted!')
                }
```

That is my code, and i get this error:

```js
                if (m.reactions.cache.get("").count <= 1) {
                                               ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'count' of undefined
    at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\Users\abhir\Downloads\Tada!\index.js:38:48)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:549:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:492:7)
```

Details:

OS: Windows Home 64 Bit
Node.JS Version: 12
Discord.JS Version: 12.0.0

Comment: the variable `m` is a freshly created message object which was sent in some channel. You haven't written any logic that retrieves the reaction. You are referencing a cache but that's old. On creation of the messagt it didn't have any reaction. So when you try to find it it will return nothing.

Comment: I have a setTimeout() though, so after 1 minute it should then only fire.

Comment: Doesn't matter. The variable `m` is a message object at creation of the message. It doesn't have any reaction. You need to refresh that variable to reflect its now state. That's a coroutine and you aren't doing another `await` statement in your code. I'm not too familiar with discord.js so I can't provide you the finished solution but I know you are missing at least another `await` statement that retrieves the current reactions from a certain message.

Comment: I tried, it didn't work though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to refetch the message on completion of the timeout :

```js
let m = await channel.send(embed);
m.react("");
            
setTimeout(() => {
    const message = channel.messages.cache.get(m.id);
    const reactions = message.reactions.cache.get("");

    if (!reactions) return message.channel.send('No reactions found.');

    if (reactions.count <= 1) {
        message.channel.send(`Reactions: ${reactions.count}`);
        return err('Not enough people reacted!');
    }
    // Do your stuff
```

Hope this will fix your issue :)

Comment: now, no matter what, it allways says "no reactions found" :(

Comment: @Aawesome you should try to log the message.reactions.cache to make sure everything is ok there

Comment: it might be the wrong method (its v12 discord.js btw)

Comment: IT WORKED TYSM!

Comment: @Aawesome happy I could have helped ! :3